# Find the equation of the Tangent Line to the given set of Parametric Equations at given point.

Tags: calculus, parametric, tangent-line

I'm looking for validation for my answer to this question.

Parametric Equations: $x = t^2 + 2t + 1 , y = t^3 + 7t^2 + 8t, t = -1$

For this problem I used the Point-Slope-Form formula.

myAnswer:$ y = 19/2X + 17$

Comment: At $t=-1$ we have $x=0$ and $y=-2$. Does this point lie on your line?

Comment: Where do I want to plug that t value

Comment: Would be better to detail your work.

Answer (score 1):

HINT

at $ t=-1 , (x_1,y_1)= (0,-2)$

$$ m=\dfrac{dy}{dx}= \dfrac{dy/dt}{dx/dt} $$

what is Point-Slope formula?

EDIT1:

slope calculation ( error corrected)

$$ \dfrac{y+2}{x}=\dfrac{3 t^2+14 t +8}{2t+2}=\dfrac{3}{0}$$

Comment: Point Slope Formula = (y -y1) = m (x-x1)

Comment: Can you apply it now?

Comment: @AlexBrito You’re going to have a bit of trouble using the point-slope formula to find an equation for a vertical line.

Comment: @amd Are you referring to the parametric equations provided above?

Comment: @Narasimham I applied t = -1 in dx/dt and dy/dt. I got (0,-3)

Comment: Hem, $t=\color{red}-1$.

Comment: @AlexBrito Apologies ,last step was in error, corrected..

Answer (score 0):

The equation of the tangent at $t$ is

$$\frac{x-f(t)}{f'(t)}=\frac{y-g(t)}{g'(t)}.$$

With the given,

$$\frac{x-0}{0}=\frac{y+2}{3}.$$

As the left denominator is zero, the tangent must be vertical, and its equation reduces to

$$x=0.$$